# Animation doesn't work when pressing two buttons - Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a 2d project in Unity and I'm having some difficulty animating the Player.

In short, the Player will have two actions, which are "Walk" and "Walk and Shoot".

However, when I set the animation to "Walk and Shoot" it doesn't play this animation.

The problem is in having to press two buttons to play the animation.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Walk", false);
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Idle", false);
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Idle_Shooting", false);
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Walk_Shooting", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Walk", true);
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Idle", false);
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Idle_Shooting", false);
        _Anim.SetBool("Player_Walk_Shooting", false);  
    }
```

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need brackets in first if (because a && b || c is not equal to a && (b || c)) and then "else" before the second if:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)))
[...]
else if(...)
```

I personaly would invert that and write:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space){
        //first option
    } else {
        //second option
    }
}
```

That looks simpler to me